# Is there a difference in meaning between "dedicated solely" and "solely dedicated"?

Tags: meaning, word-order

Rock Creek Conservancy is the only organization solely dedicated to Rock Creek Park.

Rock Creek Conservancy is the only organization dedicated solely to Rock Creek Park.

Do these statements mean the same thing?

Does one version suggest exclusivity whereas the other version suggests focus?

Comment: Yes, they do.  I might think that there's a slight difference in emphasis, but it's not significant.

Comment: I will try to make an argument for them being equivalent (although I don't feel 100% solid on this yet, and thus am not writing an Answer): Since *solely* is an adverb, it has to describe a verb, adjective, or adverb.  The only word I can find that it might modify is *dedicated*.  Since *solely* modifies the same thing in both sentences, it seems logical to conclude that the meaning is the same, which is that the only mission of this organization has to do with Rock Creek Park.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing saying  'solely dedicated' means exactly the same as 'dedicated solely' with no differences whatsoever. You might at first think  that 'dedicated solely' is somewhat different because solely goes last and captures people's attention therefore forcing them to think that it means doing only that and it is true but the other combination means pretty much the same I guess it is about the unconscious in your minds

Answer (score 0):

The difference is very subtle.  The first word of the pair receives slightly more emphasis (in terms of the thought process, not necessarily the volume of the voice), so "dedicated solely" places emphasis on the fact that the organization is "dedicated" to the stated purpose, while "solely dedicated" places emphasis on the fact that the organization is *only* dedicated to the stated purpose.